# Property does not conform to protocol

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, properties, protocols

I am having problems getting my property to conform to my self made protocol my property is declared like this:

```
    @property(assign)id <MainViewDatasource> datasource
```

And I run this code to test if it conforms to the protocol:

```
    if ([datasource conformsToProtocol:@protocol(MainViewDatasource)])
    NSLog(@"datasource conforms to MainViewDatasource");

    if(datasource == nil)
    NSLog(@"datasource is nil");
```

And in the Console it says that datasource is nil. How do I fix this?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be nil?  You didn't post any code that assigns to datasource.

Comment: A property can't conform to a protocol. That declaration declares that the `datasource` property will hold a pointer to an object that conforms to the `MainViewDatasource` protocol; the `conformsToProtocol:` test applies to the object that you have stored in the property (well, actually in its instance variable, since you're referring to the instance variable `datasource` rather than the property `self.datasource`). (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) Which is all well and good, but it means that “`datasource` conforms to `MainViewDatasource`” will only be true if and after you have created an object that conforms to that protocol and stored it there. If you don't create an object that conforms to the protocol and store it there, or if this code runs before you do, then the output will rightly tell you that `datasource` (rather, the object it points to, if any) does not conform to the protocol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't set your datasource property, it will remain at the default value, 0x0 (nil).

Comment: @SageWashabaugh: The default value of a property is `nil`. If you don't assign anything else to a property, it will continue holding `nil`. Create an object that conforms to your protocol and assign it to the property; only then will the property point to an object that conforms to your protocol.

Answer (score 0):

The code: `[datasource conformsToProtocol:@protocol(MainViewDatasource)]` itself only returns a Boolean value after it is executed.  As others have stated, it doesn't actually set up the datasource property.  If you wanted to do some set up only if the said property conforms to a protocol, you would add something to that if block:

```
if ([datasource conformsToProtocol:@protocol(MainViewDatasource)])
{    
    NSLog(@"datasource conforms to MainViewDatasource");
    // do additional set up code here that is needed, now that you know your datasource
    // conforms to the MainViewDatasource protocol.
}
if(datasource == nil)
NSLog(@"datasource is nil");
```