# sharekit gives warnings regarding conforming. Should I ignore it?

Tags: ios, sharekit

I got the sharekit library at :

https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit

I followed all the instructions and now when I run my app, I get the following warning:

```
GTMMethodCheckMethodChecker: Class UIKeyboardCandidateUtilities does not conform to @protocol(NSObject), so won't be checked
2013-03-25 23:57:42.971 Daily Tamatar[25762:c07] GTMMethodCheckMethodChecker: Class WebMIMETypeRegistry does not conform to @protocol(NSObject), so won't be checked
2013-03-25 23:57:42.973 Daily Tamatar[25762:c07] GTMMethodCheckMethodChecker: Class SLFacebookGraphUtils does not conform to @protocol(NSObject), so won't be checked
```

should I be worried? I am fairly new to protocols and conformities?

Thanks

Comment: I think here is your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450051/property-does-not-conform-to-protocol